# Cypress Stale Selector? 'Expected to find content' error

Tags: javascript, dom, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I'm using Cypress and I can't seem to google a solution for the problem I'm running into.

I'm doing the following:

```
cy.contains(label)
.siblings()
.contains(value)
.should('be.visible');
```

To make sure a status is updated after clicking a button. The issue I'm running into is Cypress can't see the label when I'm looking at the test running and it's clearly visible on the screen.

I believe it's pointing to the a stale section of the DOM and I have semi-proved this by putting in a step prior to this check which is basically a wait (a check for "is not visible" on a loading element also works).

First of all, am I right?

Secondly,
how do I make sure the above code is running on the freshest DOM possible?

Obviously I want to avoid using cy.wait, or checking for an element to not be visible as this isn't something that users care about; it feels like a bandaid fix.

Comment: At which point the test is failing `cy.contains(label)` or `contains(value)` ?

Comment: It fails at contains(value) because the label always exists, but the value is displaying the old value (which to me indicates it's referring to a stale DOM). @AlapanDas

Comment: How about you use an alias `cy.contains(label).siblings().as('sibling')`, then do something that changes the value, and then do `cy.get('@sibling').contains(value).should('be.visible');`. When we reference @sibling, Cypress checks to see if all of the elements it is referencing are still in the DOM. If they are, it returns those existing elements. If they aren't, Cypress replays the commands leading up to the alias definition.